# Apex Batch stops after 2000 records

Tags: apex, batch, governorlimits, singleemailmessage

We have an Apex batch class which processes 2950 records of contacts, sending them emails with `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage` method(The query has a filter for `IsEmailBounced = FALSE AND Email != NULL`). We run it divided to chunks of 20/40 contacts, with single usage of `Messaging.SendEmail` method per transaction(single execute chunk). We get **no errors** at all in execution but two awkward things are occurring since we added new contacts recently:

1. Only 2000(exactly) emails are sent although the QueryLocator size if of 2950 contacts.
2. The Total Batches number is changing while processing batches chunks.

Comment: Have you checked the daily external email sending limits on your org? Sending using email addresses or contact IDs count towards this limit (typically 5000 on a production org).

Comment: Forgot to mention, but of course not hitting that limit

Comment: the number `2000` makes me think of SOQL OFFSET clause which is limited to 2000. What does your `start()` method look like? (Use [edit])

Comment: return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT ID FROM Contact WHERE HasOptedOutOfEmail = FALSE AND IsEmailBounced = FALSE AND Email != NULL');

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the failing emails was the error: `The maximum number of times this file can be shared has been exceeded`
Sharing a file with `Messaging.SingleEmailMessage.SetEntityAttachments(ContentVersionIds)` has the limit of 2000 sharing per file as stated here:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_size_limits.htm&type=5

> **File Sharing Limits**
> A file can be shared a maximum of 2000 times. This
> count includes shares with records, people, and groups. If a file is
> approaching the maximum number of shares, consider creating a public
> link or making the file public by posting it to your feed.